# Python: Work on the subset of a data over a common indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe

```
df1
Out[85]: 
                    X0         X1  ...           X14                        
2011-01-03         NaN        NaN  ...           NaN                 NaN
2011-01-04    0.125194   1.125131  ...           NaN                 NaN
2011-01-05    0.399821  -0.131389  ...           NaN                 NaN
2011-01-06    1.019407   0.499459  ...           NaN                 NaN
2011-01-07    0.661913  -0.212515  ...           NaN                 NaN
               ...        ...  ...           ...                 ...
2016-12-26   -0.077632   0.125090  ...     -0.661818             -0.0325
2016-12-27   -0.038839   0.000000  ...      0.405124             -0.0275
2016-12-28    0.048546   0.224592  ...     -0.396318             -0.0025
2016-12-29    0.271423  -0.839166  ...     -0.059897              0.0025
2016-12-30   -0.602002  -0.029339  ...     -0.208157             -0.0050
```

and a series

```
y
Out[86]: 
2011-01-03    0.356858
2011-01-04    0.941385
2011-01-05   -0.060861
2011-01-06    1.258335
2011-01-07   -0.024050

2016-12-26   -0.247472
2016-12-27    0.213374
2016-12-28    0.340455
2016-12-29   -1.110743
2016-12-30    0.488538
```

I would like to regress y against a subset of df1, say, 2nd and 4th columns. How may I extract the intersections of the two indices (the days on which both have data) and then do regression?

Answer (score 1):

or you can concat the both dataframes like this:

```
df_concat = pd.concat([df1,y],sort=False, axis=1)
```

then you will get the following dataframe (from parts from your dqtaframes):

```
                   X0         X1           X2        X3        y
2016-12-26  -0.077632   0.125090    -0.661818   -0.0325 -0.247472
2016-12-27  -0.038839   0.000000    0.405124    -0.0275 0.213374
2016-12-28  0.048546    0.224592    -0.396318   -0.0025 0.340455
2016-12-29  0.271423    -0.839166   -0.059897   0.0025  -1.110743
2016-12-30  -0.602002   -0.029339   -0.208157   -0.0050 0.488538
2011-01-07  NaN          NaN         NaN         NaN    -0.024050
```

after you remove the rows with the `nans`, you can use the columns for further processing.